# Assembly - CMP not working as expected

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, att

I'm new to assembly code and I'm working on code with gdb that has this:

```
=> 0x080485ee <+132>:   cmp    %eax,0x80498d4(,%ebx,4)
   0x080485f5 <+139>:   je     0x80485fc <main+146>
   0x080485f7 <+141>:   call   0x8048540 <bomb>
```

I stopped it with a breakpoint at that line and entered these gdb commands:

```
(gdb) print $eax
$10 = 134519000
(gdb) print 0x80498d8
$11 = 134519000
(gdb) print $ebx
$12 = 1
```

From what I understand, the cmp instruction should compare the values of %eax and 0x80498d4 + (%ebx * 4), which are equal, so the code should set the zero flag and trigger je to jump to main+146 on the next line. But when I step through the code it doesn't jump:

```
(gdb) stepi 2
   0x080485ee <+132>:   cmp    %eax,0x80498d4(,%ebx,4)
   0x080485f5 <+139>:   je     0x80485fc <main+146>
=> 0x080485f7 <+141>:   call   0x8048540 <bomb>
```

Could someone please help me understand why the zero flag wasn't set and je didn't jump to main+146?

Comment: (I realize you may not know this, but someone else may) Wot syntax! Does `0x80498d4(,%ebx,4)` indeed translate to the more properly formed `[0x80498d4+4*ebx]`?

Comment: That's a memory reference, not an immediate, so you need to use the `x` command not the `p`, or dereference the pointer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

You're not translating the memory access into the correct C expression to evaluate in GDB. It should be `*(int*)(0x80498d4 + $ebx*4)`.

### Explanation

The instruction is question is `cmp %eax,0x80498d4(,%ebx,4)`, let's break down the steps of translating the `0x80498d4(,%ebx,4)` part into C:

Create a GDB convenience variable for the displacement to save some typing:

```
set variable $d = 0x80498d4
```

Translate the Displacement + Index*Scale addressing mode into an address:

```
set variable $addr = $d + $ebx*4
```

Dereference the address. This is what you were missing:

```
set variable $v = *(int*)$addr
```

The three steps above is equivalent to: `set variable $v = *(int*)($d + $ebx*4)`. Thus:

to compare the value in memory with EAX:

```
p $eax == $v
```

to set **EAX** to value in memory to make the jump happen:

```
set variable $eax = $v
```

Answer (score 0):

If I decompile this assembly code, it leads me to a C code like this:

```
if (p!=q[i])
  bomb();
```

Where p is the value held in EAX, q seems to be the base address of an array whose elements have 4 bytes each, being this base address 0x80498d4, and i is the value held in EBX, which serves as index to said array.

But you were expecting the above expression to behave like this:

```
if (p != &q[i])  /* or (p != q+i)
  bomb();
```

Which kinda make more sense to me: the value in EAX is clearly an address (a pointer) so the comparison should be made agains another pointer and it happens to be that the address of q[i] (actually, q[1] as EBX=1) has the same value, so either q is an array of pointers, or the original C code should read like the second one I've written.

Either way, the assembly code you have written compares a register against a memory value. In fact, the only assembly instruction that returns the value calculated in an expression like that (constant + register * scale) without accessing memory is the LEA instruction. All the others use these expressions to compute the effective address as LEA, and then, access memory using that address.